# with re.compile(flags=), how are the operators | and + different (if at all)?

Tags: python, regex, bitwise-operators, bitwise-or

With python regular expressions, the flags are essentially `int`s distributed as powers of 2. Their values are as follows:

```py
for flag in [re.I, re.L, re.M, re.S, re.U, re.X, re.DEBUG, re.A]:
    print(f'{flag.name:>10}', flag + 0, sep='\t')
# IGNORECASE    2
#     LOCALE    4
#  MULTILINE    8
#     DOTALL    16
#    UNICODE    32
#    VERBOSE    64
#      DEBUG    128
#      ASCII    256
```

Multiple flags can be passed to the `flags` keyword argument; the [`re` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.compile) recommends using the bitwise OR operator (`|`), but as near as I can tell, this is effectually the same as using the addition operator (`+`). In the following example, both operators yield `18`.

```py
re.I | re. S
# <RegexFlag.DOTALL|IGNORECASE: 18>
re.I + re. S
# 18
```

Other than not being the officially recommended way to do this, is there any practical reason why using the `+` operator would yield undesired results?

**NOTE:** I intend to use `|` in my code. This is purely an academic question.

Comment: Bitwise OR, `|` will or the bits of the operands without any carry. `+` would carry and produce a different result if two bits in the same position were 1.

Comment: @Todd In practice, it seems strange to do something like `flags=re.I | re.I`, but I can imagine an algorithm coming up with repeating flags. You're right that `|` is definitely more robust in that way.

Comment: Maybe there isn't any overlap with the re flags. But in other cases there can be. For instance a certain bit pattern may define a mode of an application which is a combination of several flags.. and maybe there's more than one of those complex modes.. and you want the features of both enabled.. so you'd have to OR them or you'd get an unexpected configuration if they were added.

Comment: This isn't just a Python oddity. This is prevalent in C-like languages and others.